# Filtering of a Dataset based on a column name with underscore and a nested string pattern

Tags: dataset, filtering

I have the following dataset :

```
ds=Dataset@{<|"rid" -> "#30:0", "objID" -> 1, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-TIR"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Term Information Resource"},   "out_LTSnamAlt" -> {"Index_term"}|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:1",   "objID" -> 2, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-BIR"},   "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Binary Information Resource"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:2", "objID" -> 3, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"NAM-prefer"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Base name"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:3", "objID" -> 4, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"NAM-alt"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Variant Name"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> {"prettyString"}|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:4", "objID" -> 5, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-PROP"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Occurrence"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" ->    Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:5", "objID" -> 6, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-LOC"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Locator"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:6", "objID" -> 7, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"VAL-null"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Is Null"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> {"ISNull"}|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:7", "objID" -> 9, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-ASSOC"},   "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Association"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" ->    Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:8", "objID" -> 10, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"TMAP-ROLE"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Topic Map - Association Role"},"out_LTSnamAlt" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:9", "objID" -> 11, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"NAM-abbr"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Abbreviation"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> {"Abbreviation"}|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:10", "objID" -> 12, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"REF-NULON"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Neurorganon Upper Level Ontology (NULO)"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "out_LTSnamAlt"]|>, <|"rid" -> "#30:11", "objID" -> 13, "out_LTSnamAbbr" -> {"NAM"}, "out_LTSnamPref" -> {"Proper Name String"}, "out_LTSnamAlt" -> {"Name"}|>}
```

[image]

I want to filter the rows of my dataset based on a string pattern of the column "out_LTSnamAbbr", e.g. return all rows that match "TMAP-*".

If this was a list, e.g.

```
lis = Flatten@Normal@ds[All, "out_LTSnamAbbr"];
```

I  would do

```
Select[lis, StringMatchQ[#, "TMAP" ~~ ___] &]
```

It may start like

```
ds[Select[Slot["out_LTSnamAbbr"] .... &]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work until I realized the keys for `out_LTSnamAbbr` were lists of strings with just one element, so I added `First` to get the string inside

```
ds[Select[StringMatchQ[First@#"out_LTSnamAbbr", "TMAP" ~~ ___] &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ...or `ds[Select[StringMatchQ[First @ #"out_LTSnamAbbr", "TMAP*"] &]]`.

Comment: So **that's** how you have a named slot with an underscore!